# Helper binding not updating

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a helper like so:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function bootstrapModelStatus(model) {
    if(model.get('isDeleted')) {return 'danger'};
    if(model.get('isError')) { return 'danger'};
    if(!model.get('isValid')) { return 'warning'};
    if(model.get('isSaving')) { return 'info'};
    if(model.get('isNew')) { return 'default'};
    if(model.get('isDirty')) { return 'warning'};
    if(model.get('isLoaded')) { return 'success'};
    return 'error';
}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(bootstrapModelStatus);
```

And it is bound to a DS.Model like so:

```
{{bootstrap-model-status model}}
```

The trouble is that the above does not update when the state of the model changes.  Instead I had to do the following as a bit of a hack.

```
{{bootstrap-model-status model model.currentState.stateName}}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the helper to redisplay when a property of the model you passed in changes - see [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_dependencies)

In your case, that would mean the following:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function bootstrapModelStatus(model) {
  if(model.get('isDeleted')) {return 'danger'};
  if(model.get('isError')) { return 'danger'};
  if(!model.get('isValid')) { return 'warning'};
  if(model.get('isSaving')) { return 'info'};
  if(model.get('isNew')) { return 'default'};
  if(model.get('isDirty')) { return 'warning'};
  if(model.get('isLoaded')) { return 'success'};
  return 'error';
}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(bootstrapModelStatus, 
  'isDeleted', 'isError', 'isValid', 'isSaving', 'isNew', 'isDirty',   'isLoaded'
);
```